In what way is Tam O 'Shanter "honest"?
In the first part of Robert Burns's "Tam O 'Shanter", we are introduced to Tam and learn about his upset wife waiting at home ready to yell at him for staying all evening in town to drink. Regarding these facts, we hear,

This truth fand honest Tam o' Shanter,
As he frae Ayr ae night did canter:
(Auld Ayr, wham ne'er a town surpasses,
For honest men and bonie lasses.)

My question is, in what way is Tam "honest"?
It is quite clear from the poem that Tam is an irresponsible, lazy drunk who doesn't listen to his wife, but other than in the passage above, the poem doesn't discuss his honesty at all. He doesn't tell any lies per se, but nor does he get any opportunities to choose between honesty and dishonesty, either with his wife Kate, his crony Souter Johnie, or anyone else. My 21st century education is hinting at me that he is at least honest about his problem with alcohol, but that also isn't mentioned explicitly and the concept of denial in alcoholism and the importance of being honest about one's struggles with it wasn't really a clinical concept until the early 20th century, so it wouldn't seem to apply here anyway, even if, in retrospect, Tam's life presents a clear picture of someone whose life has become unmanageable due to alcoholism. Is "honest men" meant to be an idiomatic expression representing the masculine equivalent to bonnie lasses? Is there a better way to interpret the manner in which Tam should be considered "honest"?

A look in a dictionary finds a few senses of “honest” that might be appropriate in context:

honest, adj. 2.a. Of a person: held in good esteem; respectable, reputable.
2.b. A a general epithet of appreciation or praise for a person.
4.d. Free from guile or dissimulation; ingenuous, innocent; candid, straightforward.
Oxford English Dictionary.

The phrase “honest men” is parallel to “bonie lasses”, and so “honest” seems to be a general term of approbation. The OED’s sense 2a or 2b would be suitable, but not a specific sense like “truthful”, “trustworthy”, or “sincere”. In modern English we might use “decent” in this kind of context.
In “honest Tam o’ Shanter”, we should take “honest” in the same sense as in “honest men”, as the stanza indicates that the “honest men” (for whom Ayr is the equal of any town) include Tam. However, we could also read it with the more specific senses of the word in mind, and of these sense 4d seems the aptest epithet for Tam, who shows little in the way of cunning or prudence when he encounters the witches.
